# Fullscreen code for IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to open IE8 in fullscreen mode. But it is not working. Here's the script:

```
window.open("Login.jsp","fs","fullscreen=yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. I think, the file `Login.jsp` doesn't exist or not at the proper location. Try the code with some URL like `window.open("http://www.google.com","fs","fullscreen=yes");`.